# Calling a function by String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

ok I have this small code

http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/yJtyD/

now its not really working. I had been following all the existing questions and answers here in SO but I can't make this up.

I really want to call a function without using eval()

where i had been wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute a string directly. If the function specified by the string is defined globally you can access the function by

```
window[ fn ]();
```

So in your case this would transform your code to the following:

```
var fn = "imafunc";
if (typeof window[ fn ] === 'function') {
     window[ fn ]("hello world");
}

function imafunc(str) {
    alert(str);
}
```

If the function is defined only in another function's scope, you have to resort to `eval`, which has some performance disadvantages and is generally considered bad practice ([see, e.g., MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)).

PS: This won't work in a jsFiddle as they use sandboxing, which is like defining `imafunc()` inside another function. You have to change the wrapping to use "no wrap".

Comment: thank you this works... i was thinking i can call the function directly by a string

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo (`imafunc/iamfunc`), correct it & you can (assuming global scope);

```
var fn = window["iamfunc"];

if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn("hello world");
}
```

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle of your changes, but it doesnt appear to work http://jsfiddle.net/yJtyD/1/

Comment: Change the fiddle to `no wrap (head)` as it stands Fiddle wraps the code in an event handler

Comment: eval() is a last resort in cases such as this (and most others) where there is a build in mechanic you can take advantage of (the window namespace)

Comment: is it ok i filled with a lot of things the window namespace? hehe i planning to abuse it tho...

Comment: @shareef I was thinking that if a bad guy would just able to pass a code on the eval that is existing in my codes it would be really deadly right?

Comment: You can create your own namespaces and use them; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/36Ds5/